# How to resolve vue api request before entering the target route?

Tags: vue.js

```
// inside vuex store

  actions: {
// I'm receiving this data

    async getData({ commit }) {
      await axios
        .get(`items/data`)
        .then((res) => {
          commit("SET_DATA", res.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          commit("SET_ERRORS", e);
        });
}
+
```

and inside the target routed component I'm sending the action:

```
// inside target routed component.

  created() {
    this.getData();
  },
```

But the issue is that when I reach the route only then the action is fired. So since the api request is taking some time to get resolved the routed target page is returning undefined error as the data to render the page is not yet resolved.

**So my question is that how can I resolve the axios request before entering the route?**

I tried this method:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-routing-data-fetching

but it's not working!

or is there a way to have a route resolver with vuex store:

like this:

[https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-router-route-resolvers-e7d09c991b58#:~:text=Vue%20Router%20provides%20beforeEnter%20hook,to%20bind%20our%20route%20resolver.&text=The%20resolver%20function%20is%20going,the%20destination%20route's%20meta%20key](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-router-route-resolvers-e7d09c991b58#:%7E:text=Vue%20Router%20provides%20beforeEnter%20hook,to%20bind%20our%20route%20resolver.&text=The%20resolver%20function%20is%20going,the%20destination%20route%27s%20meta%20key).

Answer (score 0):

As there is nothing like "stop execution until this HTTP request is done" in JavaScript (`await` is very different!), only way to fetch data before target route component is rendered is using `beforeRouteEnter` hook - read [Fetching Before Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation)

But I think it's easier to write your component in the way **it expects** the data is not there at first and will be available later (maybe showing some loading indicator)...